# Why is my state not updating inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn react hooks by making a small counter program, I am encountering the following issue.

In the below component I am passing counter and increment as props with default value 0 and 1 respectively. I want to set a timer when the component mounts which will update counter every second as counter = counter+increment. the increment state changes from parent component every 5 second.

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function AppHook(props) {
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(props.counter);
  let [increment, setincrement] = useState(props.increment);

  useEffect(() => {
    setincrement(props.increment);
  }, [props.increment]);

  // run only once.
  // here my increment value is always 1 even if the upper hook updates
  // it whenever parent changes it. Why is this happening?
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component did mount");
    setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter => counter + increment);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return <div className="AppHook" />;
}
```

Comment: The answer is already in the comment: `run only once.`. The effect is only executed the first time the component renders, thus capturing the value of `increment` at that moment in time. If you want to get the "current" value of `increment` then `increment` should be a dependency of the effect. You will also need to return a cleanup function so that previous intevals are removed correctly.

Comment: But the set interval is supposed to run that function every second, now every time that function runs doesn't it take the increment value from state?

Comment: *"now every time that function runs doesn't it take the increment value from state?"* No. It refers to the `increment` variable that existed at that moment in time. It only gets `counter` from the current state, since you are passing a function to `setCounter`. I recommend to give https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html a thorough read.

Comment: This might also help: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Check the dependency list.  first ``useEffect``` will run when ```increment``` changes and it never does. Add ```counter``` to the dependency list of first ```useEffect```.

Comment: @aaKhan increment changes every 5 seconds. I mentioned it. It's done in parent component and passed down to this component as props.

Comment: Can you update the question with the parent component as well? I was able to reproduce what you did here and the counter is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-voice-lqowk?fontsize=14

Comment: @ElderPattenFerreira https://github.com/facinick/counterIssue

Comment: **CLEARING DOUBTS** 
1. I want to run the useEffect JUST ONCE, that's why the dependency list for that is [], it acts like component did mount.
2. The setCounter is calling by timer every second like this: **setCounter(0+1)** instead of **setCounter(counter+increment)**  which is the cause of the issue, it uses counter and increment to take the value just once and for all.
3. Increment is updated by parent component every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue arises from your state being spread around incorrectly.

In Parent JS:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import AppHook from './AppHook';

const ParentApp = props => {
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
const [increment, setIncrement] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(setIncrement(increment++), 5000);
}, []);
return (
    <Fragment>
        Increment is {increment}
        Counter is <AppHook counter={counter} setCounter={setCounter} increment={increment} />
    </Fragment>
);
};
```

in Child.js (apphook.js):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';

const AppHook = props => {
    const { counter, setCounter, increment } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(setCounter(increment), 1000);
    }, []);

    return <Fragment> {counter} </Fragment>;
};
```